# Retrieving cookies from another HTML page - link based option select

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

firstly thanks for anyone taking the time to read this.

I've spent quite a bit of time trying to work this out for myself with little success. I have created a script to store cookies from a user input - here's a public link to what I've got so far [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oliverbrown/jup1x7cz/) .

If I wanted to retrieve the user information on another `html` page on the same site - what would I have to do? (I'm using `cookie.js` to handle the script)

Is it possible for the user to be diverted to another page based on a selection in the drop down, but still collecting the cookies.

The end result would be for - user enters personal info and selects from drop down menu, then click go - go links to a page specified by user selection on drop down menu - new page contains user info  from cookies.

FYI the `.container div` in the fiddle is just to test the cookies
Thanks in advance

```
<input id="firstName" type="text">
 <select id="service">
  <option value="plumbing">Plumbing</option>
  <option value="Handyman">Handyman</option>
  <option value="odd-jobs">Odd Jobs</option>
  <option value="electrical">Electricale</option>
 </select>

 <button id="go">go</button>
 <div class="container"></div>

$("#go").on("click", function(e) {
name = $("#firstName").val();
service = $("#service").val();
Cookies.set('Name', name);
Cookies.set('Service', service)
var Uname = Cookies.get('Name');var Uservice = Cookies.get('Service');

$("div.container").html("<p>Hello " + Uname + ".</p><p>You would like to book " + Uservice + "!</p>");});
```

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are stored by domain (or subdomain).
So the cookies you set on one page - will be available on another page of the same website.

Comment: Hi Guy, this doesn't really answer my question. I know that the cookies are stored on the domain or sub domain level by default. The question is about how to access the above variables from another page. I.e if I wanted that .container div to show on another html what would the script be